# Soap: How to deal with non XML 1.0 characters

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am having some problems with a SoapServer sending me some responses with some invalid XML 1.0 chars like **U+001F** throwing a SoapFault "looks like we got no XML document".

My current code is:

```
class SoapClientNG extends \SoapClient {

    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) {

        $xml = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way); 
        $response = str_ireplace('&#x1F;', '', $xml);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to **convert all** non 1.0 chars to nothing or even a way to enable SoapClient to accepts xml 1.1?

Comment: What encoding does your xml document specify? Where in the XML does that character appear?

Comment: encoding UTF-8 and the char appears in the middle of the soap response

Comment: inside a tag that contains other text, or outside of tags? or within the tag names itself?

Comment: as a value (text) of one of tags